# Ghost any way to factorize HTML patterns?

Tags: ghost-blog, ghost

my title isn't brilliant, but I don't know exactly how to put it, I lack some knowledge. If you have a better title, please let me know :)

But the question is simple. Let me tell you the story. I blog with [Ghost](https://ghost.org/), and as most of us, I put some images in my blog.

I don't use the [native way](http://support.ghost.org/add-image-post/) to insert images in my blog, aka:

```
![Ghost Logos](https://ghost.org/assets/logos.png)
```

Doing it this way is too restrictive, it doesn't allow you to add a caption or to change the image width. Instead, I write the HTML directly, and it looks like that:

```
<figure>
<img src="https://ghost.org/assets/logos.png" alt="Ghost Logos" width="80%"/>
<figcaption>Here come the logos</figcaption>
</figure>
```

And it works great! My only concern is that I have to copy/paste this all the time, which a little bit tedious.

So I was wondering if there is any way to, say, define a kind of function or macro or whatever, so that I just have to call it with some arguments (image source, width, caption), and it's automatically replaced by the HTML.

I know there are plenty of technologies under the hood of Ghost (Markdown, Handlebars, and probably much more), and that it can do a lot of magic. But I don't know ho to invoke it...

So if you're this kind of wizard and know a way to achieve that, please let me know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Before apps come along I don't really see this being possible within Ghost.*

Until then I would suggest using some extension for the browser, either a Macro extension or something like [Auto Text Expander](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-text-expander-for-go/iibninhmiggehlcdolcilmhacighjamp/support) which allows you to define your own shortcuts. You could for example use the following as an expansion for your figure-element:

*Input:* `!!`

*Output:*

```
<figure>
    <img src="<!--?atec?-->" alt="">
    <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Hi @Reedyn, thanks for the hint, it does the job indeed ! I use Firefox so I settled on an equivalent add-on named [Text Complete](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/text-complete/). Thx !